# ElectronJS autostarting for current user but not for all users on machine

Tags: javascript, windows, active-directory, electron

I have create a electronJS application (for windows) which should be auto launch on login and restart. Application installer is machine wide (not only for current user). This is working fine for current user from which application is installed but when i login from other user of machine, application is not auto launching i have to open the application manually and after that application will start auto launching when user will login or restart. i want application to auto launch for all users without opening it manually for first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any option to do the mentioned above in electron's setLoginItemSetting API also not in npm auto-launch package. So i did it by installer.nsh file. By this file when installation complete it insert value into windows registry and on uninstall it removes the value from registry. Hope this will help!